# Cannot provision MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2007

I just installed MOSS 2007 with service pack 2 on Windows 2008 R2 SP 1. When provisioning the server I am getting the following error.

> system.argumentoutofrangeexception index was out of range

I have the enterprise version and I did a stand-alone install. I am using SQL Server version 2005 SP 4. Do I need to install Windows 2008 instead of trying to use Windows 2008 R2? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing MOSS 2007 with Service Pack 2 fixed the issue.

> [Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Trial Version (x64)](http://MOSS%20Shared%20Services%20Administration)

I was able to find the link for the 32-bit version but it is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of **MOSS RTM** or **MOSS with SP1** is not supported on Windows Server 2008 R2. Meanwhile **MOSS 2007 SP2** is supported on Windows Server 2008 R2.

So make sure that you have `Sharepoint Server (MOSS) with Service Pack 2` to be able to install it on `Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1`.

For more details check

- [Installing SharePoint 2007 on SQL 2008 R2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/priyo/2010/09/20/installing-sharepoint-2007on-sql-2008-r2/)
- [Install MOSS 2007 & WSS 3.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 – you will need SP2 slipstream](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/opal/2009/05/07/install-moss-2007-wss-3-0-on-windows-server-2008-r2-you-will-need-sp2-slipstream/)

Comment: I slip streamed SP 2 into the installer.

Comment: what is the SQL server version?

Comment: 2005 express which comes with the install. I installed SP 4. I initially tried to use your second guide but I was unable to perform the install with the WSS files in the update folder. When I did I got the error the product id specified was not found on this machine. Could this be why it isn't working?

Comment: Does anyone know what causes this error? Am I going to have to install Windows 2008? Please help.

Comment: I'd try to download the MOSS 2007 + SP2 and try that install without slipstreaming